# Attachment content is empty

Tags: apex, attachment, blob, base64, encodingutil

I have a boomi process which takes the file content and send it to salesforce to create attachment. But attachment is blank.

Here is my code:

```
String jsonStr = 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABo4AAAMgCAYAAAAdtpBIAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAAFiUAABYlAUlSJPAAAP+lSURBVHhe7P15dFRXnub9qv6447p/9Fq3V+aq9d57q7vve7u6K7s6q1z9ZnWnszOd2W47M92Zdk52OT2nZ4zxANgYbAwGbAy2Gcw8GMw8g5kHM8/zIECMEgIJxCjmGf9uPFuxxVHElhQKhRQh6fhBBCCCGEEEIIIYQQQgghzSNVi6PnIx8TE7s9tAJCCCGEEEIIIYQQQgghhBDSPJL3b5//2v7tCxXT0bnPn';
Attachment attach = new Attachment();
attach.contentType = 'image/png';
attach.name = 'test.png';
attach.parentId = '0010H00002DW2Ds';
attach.body = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(jsonStr);
insert attach;
```

Attachment is inserted but there is no content inside. Is there anything I am doing wrong.

Thank you,
Thiru

Comment: What is the File type here?

Comment: I have answered a similar question here, please check https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/180211/save-base64-data-as-attachment

Comment: As I see the base64 is of the image, so you need to set the file type as 'image/png'
att.contentType = 'image/png';

Comment: I have updated my new code in my question. But its still showing empty content. may be my base64 data is wrong.?

I took the content from already attached image.
Attachment atts = [SELECT ID,Body,ContentType FROM Attachment WHERE ID = '00Pp000000FskcuEAB'];
String body1 = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(atts.Body);

Comment: Thank you @Saroj Bera

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This file looks like a legitimate PNG file fragment when saved and downloaded. Reading through the file, we see:

| tag | length | data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Magic | 8 | iVBORw0KGgo= // PNG HEADER |
| IHDR | 13 | Width = 1678, Height = 800, Bit Depth = 8, Color Type = 6, Compression Method = 0, Filter Method = 0, Interlace Method = 0 |
| sRGB | 1 | 0 |
| gAMA | 4 | 45455 |
| pHYS | 9 | X = 5669, Y = 5669, Unit = Meters |
| IDAT | 255 | Pixel data 165 bytes long |

Here the file trails off. There should be an `IEND` specifying the end of the image, but it doesn't exist. My conclusion is that the file is a fragment of what would be a valid PNG, but the rest of the file is missing.

Comment: Its working finally. The body content was invalid